# Azure Automation script to request OMS

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I wrote an Automation script in PowerShell which give me every morning a report about our azure subscriptions (Vm, Automation jobs, alerts, ...).
Now, I'm adding a new function which works well from my computer but fails when run from Automation and I don't find how to make it work.

Works well from my computer (VS code / PS 5.1 / PS 4.0)

```
$omsRGname = "xxx"
$omsWorkspaceName = "xxx"
$omsQueryThreat = 'Type=ProtectionStatus ThreatStatusRank!=150 ThreatStatusRank!=470 | select Computer,Threat,ThreatStatus'
$ArrayThreat = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

function OmsRequest {
    Param(
        [parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsRG,
        [parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsWorkspace,
        [parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsQuery
    )
    Process {
        Import-Module AzureRm.OperationalInsights
        $error.clear()
        $Result.clear
        $script:Result = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults -ResourceGroupName $omsRG -WorkspaceName $omsWorkspace -Query $omsQuery
        $reqIdParts = $Result.Id.Split("/")
        $reqId = $reqIdParts[$reqIdParts.Count - 1]
        $wait = Get-Date
        while ($Result.Metadata.Status -eq "Pending" -and $error.Count -eq 0) {
            $Result = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults -WorkspaceName $omsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $omsRG -Id $reqId
            #debug
            $elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $wait
            Write-Output "Elapsed: $elapsedTime -- Status: $($Result.Metadata.Status)"
            Write-Output "Count: $($Result.Count)"
        }
    }
}

OmsRequest $omsRGname $omsWorkspaceName $omsQueryThreat
#debug
Write-Output "VALUEOUT:" $Result.Value
#
$OMSComputers = $Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json
if ($OMSComputers) {
    foreach ( $ThreatDetails in $OMSComputers) {
        <#write "$(get-date($ThreatDetails.__metadata.TimeGenerated) -format G) - $($ThreatDetails.Computer) - $($ThreatDetails.Threat) - $($ThreatDetails.ThreatStatus)"#>
        $ThDetails = [PSCustomObject] @{
            Date         = (get-date($ThreatDetails.__metadata.TimeGenerated) -format G);
            Computer     = $ThreatDetails.Computer;
            Threat       = $ThreatDetails.Threat;
            ThreatStatus = $ThreatDetails.ThreatStatus;
        }
        $ArrayThreat.Add($ThDetails) |Out-Null
    }
}
else {Write-Output "OK"}

$ArrayThreat
```

from my local computer

```
Elapsed: 00:00:00.4270000 -- Status: Successful
Count: 1

Date                Computer      Threat                   ThreatStatus
----                --------      ------                   ------------
29/06/2017 12:55:37 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 11:48:28 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 10:55:37 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 09:55:38 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 08:48:28 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 08:48:28 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 07:55:37 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 07:55:37 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 06:48:28 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
29/06/2017 06:48:28 xxx.local     Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT   Quarantined
```

When I run my code from Automation, I get this error

```
ConvertFrom-Json : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does 
not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:164 char:33
+ $OMSComputers = $Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ({
  "Computer"...ng": {}
  }
}:JObject) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Well, my error is here

```
$OMSComputers = $Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json
```

When I look into its value, I get this (just took one property from the list given by $Result.Value)

```
VALUEOUT:

Name                       : Computer
Type                       : Property
HasValues                  : True
First                      : {}
Last                       : {}
Count                      : 1
Parent                     : {Computer, Threat, ThreatStatus, __metadata}
Root                       : {Computer, Threat, ThreatStatus, __metadata}
Next                       : {}
Previous                   : 
Path                       : Computer
LineNumber                 : 0
LinePosition               : 0
IsReadOnly                 : False
AllowNew                   : True
AllowEdit                  : True
AllowRemove                : True
SupportsChangeNotification : True
SupportsSearching          : False
SupportsSorting            : False
IsSorted                   : False
SortProperty               : 
SortDirection              : Ascending
IsFixedSize                : False
SyncRoot                   : System.Object
IsSynchronized             : False
```

isee this line

```
Keys                       : {Computer, Threat, ThreatStatus, __metadata}
```

I've tried to parse it as a hashtable, but with no result.

Does anyone have any other creative ways to solve this?
Thanks

Edit:
I've only past my function here. But in the full script I'm well connected and the PS module is already there (if not the function fail telling me, the RG can not be found, but in spite of, I click and add the module from your Link).
If I look at the $result content I get the query result.

```
{
    "Computer": "xxx.local",
    "Threat": "Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT",
    "ThreatStatus": "Quarantined",
    "__metadata": {
        "Type": "ProtectionStatus",
        "TimeGenerated": "2017-06-29T10:55:37.77Z",
        "highlighting": {}
    }
}
```

when I ask for its type

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
```

So I import the Newtonsoft.Json module and try to convert from this kind of JSON but it's failing too.

It's looks like my OMS query is working (I have a result in $Result) but when Automation try to convert with 'ConvertFrom-Json', it fails.

```
#debug
Write-Output "VALUEOUT:"
Write-Output "Get-variable RESULT"
Get-Variable Result -ValueOnly |format-list
$OMSComputers = $Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Output:

```
    VALUEOUT:
    Get-variable RESULT

    Id       : subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Operatio
               nalInsights/workspaces/xxx/search/xxx|10.1.0.27|2017-07-05T14-33-52Z
    Metadata : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.OperationalInsights.Models.PSSearchMetadata
    Error    : 
    Value    : {"Computer": "xxx.local" "Threat": "Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT" "ThreatStatus": "Quarantined" 
               "__metadata": {
                 "Type": "ProtectionStatus",
                 "TimeGenerated": "2017-06-29T10:55:37.77Z",
                 "highlighting": {}
               }, "Computer": "xxx.local" "Threat": "Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT" "ThreatStatus": "Quarantined" 
               "__metadata": {
                 "Type": "ProtectionStatus",
                 "TimeGenerated": "2017-06-29T09:48:28.42Z",
                 "highlighting": {}
               }, "Computer": "xxx.local" "Threat": "Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT" "ThreatStatus": "Quarantined" 
               "__metadata": {
                 "Type": "ProtectionStatus",
                 "TimeGenerated": "2017-06-29T08:55:37.757Z",
                 "highlighting": {}
               }, "Computer": "xxx.local" "Threat": "Virus:ALisp/Bursted.DT" "ThreatStatus": "Quarantined" 
               "__metadata": {
                 "Type": "ProtectionStatus",
                 "TimeGenerated": "2017-06-29T07:55:38.327Z",
                 "highlighting": {}
               }...}

ConvertFrom-Json : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does 

not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

At line:65 char:33

+ $OMSComputers = $Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json

+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ({

  "Computer"...ng": {}

  }

}:JObject) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

I don't get why the ConvertFrom-Json fails

Answer (score 0):

In Azure automation account, it does not support import module by using `Import-Module AzureRm.OperationalInsights`. Your error root reason is `$script:Result` is null. You need import `AzureRm.OperationalInsights` to your Azure automation account. Please refer to this following steps:

1.Open the [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.OperationalInsights/3.1.0).

2.Click `Deploy to Azure Automation`.

3.Delete `Import-Module AzureRm.OperationalInsights` in your runbook.

Note: When you execute `Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults`, you need login to Azure in the runbook, according to your runbook, it seems that you don't have the step. If you don't do it, please add it to your runbook.

The following runbook works for me.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

##
$omsRGname = "shuivm"
$omsWorkspaceName = "shuitest"
$omsQueryThreat = 'Type=ProtectionStatus ThreatStatusRank!=150 ThreatStatusRank!=470 | select Computer,Threat,ThreatStatus'
$ArrayThreat = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

function OmsRequest {
    Param(
        [parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsRG,
        [parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsWorkspace,
        [parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsQuery
    )
    Process {

        $error.clear()
        $Result.clear
        $script:Result = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults -ResourceGroupName $omsRG -WorkspaceName $omsWorkspace -Query $omsQuery
        $reqIdParts = $Result.Id.Split("/")
        $reqId = $reqIdParts[$reqIdParts.Count - 1]
        $wait = Get-Date
        while ($Result.Metadata.Status -eq "Pending" -and $error.Count -eq 0) {
            $Result = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults -WorkspaceName $omsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $omsRG -Id $reqId
            #debug
            $elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $wait
            Write-Output "Elapsed: $elapsedTime -- Status: $($Result.Metadata.Status)"
            Write-Output "Count: $($Result.Count)"
        }
    }
}

OmsRequest $omsRGname $omsWorkspaceName $omsQueryThreat
#debug
Write-Output "VALUEOUT:" $Result.Value
#
$OMSComputers = $Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json
if ($OMSComputers) {
    foreach ( $ThreatDetails in $OMSComputers) {
        <#write "$(get-date($ThreatDetails.__metadata.TimeGenerated) -format G) - $($ThreatDetails.Computer) - $($ThreatDetails.Threat) - $($ThreatDetails.ThreatStatus)"#>
        $ThDetails = [PSCustomObject] @{
            Date         = (get-date($ThreatDetails.__metadata.TimeGenerated) -format G);
            Computer     = $ThreatDetails.Computer;
            Threat       = $ThreatDetails.Threat;
            ThreatStatus = $ThreatDetails.ThreatStatus;
        }
        $ArrayThreat.Add($ThDetails) |Out-Null
    }
}
else {Write-Output "OK"}

$ArrayThreat
```

Comment: hi, just tried your code, i have the very same error with "| ConvertFrom-Json". I edited the first post.

Comment: @Folk I check `$Result.Value` is not a `json` format, it is a text format. Do you want to convert to json? If yes. You should use `$Result.Value|ConvertTo-Json`. `ConvertTo-Json` is convert file to a json format. If no, what is the result `$Result.Value` on your local Power Shell. Is it `Json` format?  If you only want to use text format, I think you don't need use `ConvertFrom-Json`.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem with the command:
`$Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json`

This behavior is happening both in an automation runbook and executing locally

This is my workaround to extract the $result.Value from a query using a ForEach and passing the values to a hashtable:

```
  $dynamicQuery = "* | measure count() by Type"
$now = Get-Date
$StartDateAndTime = $now.AddHours(-24).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")

$EndDateAndTime = $now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")

$result = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults `
-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
-WorkspaceName $WorkSpaceName `
-Query $dynamicQuery `
-Start $StartDateAndTime `
-End $EndDateAndTime 

 $queryResults = new-object System.Collections.Hashtable

Foreach ($item in $result.value)
{
 $obj1 = $item["Type"].ToString()
   $obj2= $item["AggregatedValue"].ToString()
  [void]$queryResults.Add($obj1,$obj2)
}

Write-Output $queryResults
```

I've added it as an issue here, as this is not how the module is documented and this is not an elegant solution: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/4256

Comment: hi, it's works from my computer (win7 - PS5.1/4.0) [$OMSComputers = $Result.Value | ConvertFrom-Json], but fail into Automation. I show the result from my computer into my first post. i'll try your solution, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Folk - this is a bug with AzureRM.Operational.Insights 3.2.0

Testing confirms that 3.0.1 will return proper JSON in $result.Value

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to upload this older module to Azure, it always fails on 'Extracting Activities'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help :)

here is the debug code i've used (and already add to our production MorningReport script)  while the module is broken

```
###Query OMS for malware state
#MorningMalwareDebug region Authentication
Write-Verbose ""
Write-Verbose "------------------------ Authentication ------------------------"
Write-Verbose "Logging in to Azure ..."
try {
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
    $null = Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -SubscriptionName "xxxx" `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    Write-Verbose "Successfully logged in to Azure." 
} 
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection) {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } 
    else {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
#MorningMalwareDebug endregion Authentication
####
#MorningMalwareDebug region Function
function OmsRequest {
    Param(
        [parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsRG,
        [parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsWorkspace,
        [parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)]
        $omsQuery
    )
    Process {
        Import-Module AzureRm.OperationalInsights
        $error.clear()
        $Result.clear
        $script:Result = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults -ResourceGroupName $omsRG -WorkspaceName $omsWorkspace -Query $omsQuery -Start $FromStartDate -End $ToEndDate
        $reqIdParts = $Result.Id.Split("/")
        $reqId = $reqIdParts[$reqIdParts.Count - 1]
        $wait = Get-Date
        while ($Result.Metadata.Status -eq "Pending" -and $error.Count -eq 0) {
            $Result = Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsSearchResults -WorkspaceName $omsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $omsRG -Id $reqId
            $elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $wait
            Write-Output "Elapsed:" $elapsedTime "-- Status:" $Result.Metadata.Status
        }
    }
}
#MorningMalwareDebug endregion Function
####
#MorningMalwareDebug region Variables
$now = Get-Date
$FromStartDate = $now.AddHours(-24).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
$ToEndDate = $now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
$omsRGname = "xxxx"
$omsWorkspaceName = "xxxx"
$omsQueryThreat = 'Type=ProtectionStatus ThreatStatusRank!=150 ThreatStatusRank!=470 | select Computer,Threat,ThreatStatus'
$ArrayThreat = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
#MorningMalwareDebug endregion Variables
####
#MorningMalwareDebug region Main
OmsRequest $omsRGname $omsWorkspaceName $omsQueryThreat
if ($Result.value) {
    $ArrayThreat.clear()
    Foreach ($ThreatDetails in $Result.value) {
        $ThDetails = [PSCustomObject] @{
            Computer     = ($ThreatDetails["Computer"].ToString()).split('.')[0];
            Threat       = $ThreatDetails["Threat"].ToString();
            ThreatStatus = $ThreatDetails["ThreatStatus"].ToString();
        }
        $ArrayThreat.Add($ThDetails)
    }
    Write-Output $ArrayThreat
}
else {write-output "Pas de menace"}
#MorningMalwareDebug endregion Main
####
#MorningMalwareDebug region BuildMail
#MorningMalwareDebug endregion BuildMail
####
#MorningMalwareDebug region SendMail
#MorningMalwareDebug endregion SendMail
```